# i want to find how much memory javascript object uses in firefox

Tags: memory-management

is there a tool for firefox. i tried about:memory and about:cache. 
i want the memory usage by particular js object

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug:
http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Memory_Profiler